# Is there a way to talk to animals without having Pet Pal on any of my characters?

Tags: divinity-original-sin-2

I want to talk to the pig (after blessing them) in the quest *The Burning Pigs* of Divinity Original Sin 2 but I don't have the Pet Pal talent. And I don't want to invest a point in it for now.

As this is an RPG with multiple ways of accomplishing goals, is there any other way to talk to this pig? Maybe switching to another race that has that talent (with the Mask of the Shapeshifter)? Or with an item? Or finding a character (recruitable or NPC) who can talk to the pig in our place?

I'm not only interested in talking to this particular pig but also talking to animals without Pet Pal in general.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ifan has access to pet pal, try recruiting him into your party and using him to talk to the pigs instead.
However, you can only recruit him later in the story and you'd gain access to the respec mirror by that point. He's still handy to have around in case you don't want to run laps just to talk to animals.

Comment: +1 Ifan has access to Pet Pal via his Wanderer class. I missed _Or finding a character_, implying that the OP doesn't have a full party yet.

Comment: @Schism I've had a full party for dozens of hours already. By *finding a character* I was meaning an NPC. I've edited my question to clarify this.

Comment: I believe any companion whatsoever can also have Pet Pal if recruited as either a Wayfarer or Conjurer (according to this [table](https://i.imgur.com/71YEvGY.png))

Answer (score 10):

*Pet Pal* is a talent associated with preset classes, not races. Outside of character creation, you can only gain this talent by respeccing.

If you just want to talk to animals, you can activate the *Animal Empathy* mod from *Larian Modifications* in the in-game pause menu. This mod allows all characters to speak with animals without a talent requirement.

Note however that activating this mod (or any other) will disable achievements on Steam. However, since this is a bundled mod, this is useable even from non-PC versions of the game.